# Swift - Header UICollectionViewController dynamic height

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm currently coding the main page of my app, which is a `UICollectionViewController` with an header.

In the header, I have many `Labels` and `Buttons`.
I would like to have a dynamic height, thanks to the constraints set, but I didn't find how to do it or any answer on stackoverflow...

A Screenshot of the Header (truncated)
[image]

> 1. Fetch the data with Firebase
> 2. Send the data to an UICollectionReusableView
> 3. Labels are updated in it

So the process is like that:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

      let headerViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! WodCollectionReusableView

      headerViewCell.wod = self.wod // pass the info
      headerViewCell.layoutIfNeeded()

      return headerViewCell
}
```

If you know if there is a way to do it like we can do it for cells it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    return CGSize(width: self.myCollectionView.bounds.width, height: self.mylabel.bounds.height)
}
```

> try this May help you

Comment: Thank you but I can access to self.mylabel.bounds.height given that the labels are in the UICollectionReusableView